# NUllPointerException on non null String

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am working an a small database assignment, and I seem to get a weird nullPointerException where I cannot find the problem

The following snippet is the error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at interfaces.FindDueActivityForFriend$1.actionPerformed(FindDueActivityForFriend.java:65)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As you can see the problem occurs in the 65 of the FindDueActivityForFriend class, and to be more specific in this code snippet:

```
    friendSearch = friendSearchField.getText();
            console.out("Searching for the name that was entered");
            console.out("friendSearch variable is: " + friendSearch );

            if(con.GetNameExcists(friendSearch )){
//more code
```

the error occurs at the if statement. 
In this if statement a class is called that connects to the database, checks if a name is already in the database, and then returns a true if that name is already in the database.

I have used that specific method around 10 times around the program without problems, but not this time.

the console.out("String"); that I am calling just before it is for a small console windows that I made that just prints what I tell it to, this is to have a console when not running the application out of for example eclipse.

I tried printing the variable just to see what it was, and it is not null. 
following is a copy paste of the console:

```
    [Wed May 14 20:04:26 CEST 2014] [INFO] Opened the findDueForFriend screen
    [Wed May 14 20:04:30 CEST 2014] [INFO] Searching for the name that was entered
    [Wed May 14 20:04:30 CEST 2014] [INFO] FriendSearch variable is: Ylva
```

I went on into ant debugger, and is doesn't even go in the method, it throws the nullpointer before actually opening the method

I don't have a clue what I am doing wrong anymore so if anyone has any suggestions please post them.

just for completeness here is the declaration of the variable aswell:

```
    String friendSearch;

public FindDueActivityForFriend(Console Console){
    console = Console;
    friendSearch = "";
```

I even tried declaring the String as an empty string, not sure if that makes it not null but I think it should, and the console window clearly shows that the string contains something before throwing the nullpointer exception...

Comment: Everything you describe indicates that `con` is probably `null`.  How have you verified that it isn't?

Comment: ugh facepalm. jup forgot to initialise the con variable, can't believe that I just spend an hour trying to fix the string and forgot to look at the con variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it occurs in this if statement

```
if(con.GetNameExcists(friendSearch ))
```

and you know that friendSearch is not null, then con must be null, in order to get a NullPointerException in the if statement.

Comment: Jup, as stated in the comment above, I was to blind to see it was not the string but the con variable.... sorry for bother but thank all of you for the quick response on my failing

Comment: @Ylva A easy way to solve this in the future is to look at what references on the line are actually being dereferenced within the if statement, and in your if statement that is only con.

Comment: okay so what you are saying is that if friendSearch was null, that it wouldn't throw the nullPointer in this line but would throw it in the first line in the GetNameExcists method where it would be used?

Comment: Yes, ideally at least, but it may depend on your compiler. Line info can sometimes not translate perfectly and you'll end up with an incorrect line number that is at least somewhat near the actual. I don't remember if I have seen this happen in Java though using the Oracle implementation, but I have definitely seen it in some other languages I've worked in. In this case, if friendSearch is null, then that's the same as calling GetNameExcists(null), eventually getNameExcists will attempt to deference that null value on one of it's own lines of code, and you'll get the exception there.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, I have run some tests and indeed if I where to do GetNameExcists(null) (when making sure the variable is empty) then it does indeed just keep on going till inside that method, I didn't know java behaved this way but thats something that I will keep in mind in futher debugging problems.

Answer (score 0):

the only possibility  with the below code is

```
 if(con.GetNameExcists(friendSearch ))
```

either `con` is `null` or `friendSearch`  is `null` which you might be accessing at the

begining of the method and performing some operation like `friendSearch.caoncat` or something.

mostly it should  be `con is null` it seems.

try to print `con` value inside log.

Answer (score 0):

if con.getNameExcists(...) return Boolean instead of boolean and possibly returns null, then you get a NullPointerException from auto-unboxing.

Comment: it returns a boolean, but as noted above the problem was in the initialisation of the con variable